# My temperature gauge slowly goes to top then car dies

Tags: civic

I replaced battery and now after starting the car and driving it for less than 70 feet temperature guage slowly rises to top and car loses electrical power.  Then guage goes down and power restored.  the radiator is not hot.

Comment: Sorry but this is not enough information to help your diagnose your problem. It is not possible to damage the vehicle by replacing the battery unless you short the the terminals on the battery together while they are connected to the vehicle.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How old is the car? What mileage? How long has it been since it was previously started? Is it summer or winter where you are? Have you checked or flushed the radiator? Any accident damage? Has any major work been done on the car recently? Did the car have any other problems?